# Under what circumstances does TeX produce a series of tokens with space after a control sequence?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

On page 39 of *The TeXbook*, Knuth said,

> Furthermore, spaces
> are not ignored after control sequences inside a token list; the ignore-space rule applies
> only in an input file, during the time that strings of characters are being tokenized.

His words confuse me, under what circumstances does TeX produce a series of tokens with space after a control sequence? The output seems like this `<cs>, space_10, a_11, 3_12`, what input can make TeX produce this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, for example:

```
\def\macro#1{#1 a3}
```

When you use `\macro\cs` then it is expanded to `\cs`, `space`, `a`, `3`.

Comment: I get it, thanks.